# Open .xlsm strictly with Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want my macro enabled `.xlsm` file, to be opened using Excel only.

Can I know & deny other applications trying to open it?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
...
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a particular application you're concerned with? I can't think of a way to prevent the file being *read* and the Workbook_Open is only likely to be 'run' by Excel. I guess an XLSB file might give you some protection from other applications.

Comment: Thanks. Would check it out..

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to deny it on your own machine through your OS's setup; however since it's the OS that's doing the "Opening" you have little to no control over someone else's machine. Your best bet would be to password protect the workbook via: file>save as>computer>browse>tools>general options.